# Spring Security - What does JWT offer me?

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I am looking at making my application more secure and getting my head around everything that is going on.

I have a login with Spring Boot. This login calls a UserDetailsService implementation like so:

```
   public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username)
        throws UsernameNotFoundException {

    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (user.getUsername().isEmpty()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(
                "No user found with username: "+ username);
    }

    String role;

    if (user.getUserType().contains("Gp")){
        role = "ROLE_GP";
    }

    else if(user.getUserType().contains("Patient")){
        role = "ROLE_PATIENT";
    }

    else {
        role = "ROLE_ADMIN";
    }

    boolean enabled = true;
    boolean accountNonExpired = true;
    boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
    boolean accountNonLocked = true;
    return  new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
            (user.getUsername(),
                    user.getPassword(), enabled, accountNonExpired,
                    credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked,
                    getAuthorities(Arrays.asList(role)));
}

private static List<GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities (List<String> roles) {
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String role : roles) {
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }
    return authorities;
}
```

This creates me a session with user roles so I can configure the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter etc.

So my question is what exactly does adding the filters with JWT do? Does Spring Security do these by default already because what I have done already creates an authorized and authenticated user.

Thanks.

Comment: I see no JWT related code in the question.

Comment: There isn't. The question was, what would JWT add? It has been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On higher level:

What you have achieved is `statefull authentication`. While JWT provides you stateless authentication for your applications (no need to create/destroy any session. Each request carry a token to access the resource. ). Although, with JWT also you can have statefull authentication.

Technically:

In both approaches, the end result is same. The main difference is, in your approach you have taken the responsibility to authenticate the user and provide authorities. While in JWT,  the responsibility to authenticate the user belongs to third party called **Authorization server**. In your application you just validate the JWT and depending on the authorities, allow or deny the access to required resource.

Depending on your requirements and architecture, you can pick any. In microservice world, the stateless approach is more common and best suited.

> So my question is what exactly does adding the filters with JWT do?
>   Does Spring Security do these by default

Depends how you implement it. Usually JWT filter first validates the token by signature or encryption and then reads the user authorities from JWT. So there is no need to have any implementation of userDetails service.

Comment: So there is no difference in security?

Comment: I just updated the answer. Please have a look and let me know what else you want?